# Python Pandas Dataframe: replace variable by the frequency count

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

I have a dataframe which has categorical variables with hundreds of different values.

I'm able to verify the frequency of these levels using the 'values_count()' function of using a groupby statement + reset_index() ...

I was trying to replace these hundreds of values by their frequency count (and later on merge levels with low cardinality). I was trying to join two different dataframes (one with the values and the other with the counts), but I'm having issues...

For example, the frequency table would be below, with around 300 records (all unique):

```
    v_catego  Time
0        AA   353
1       AAC   136
2       ABB     2
3       ABC     1
4       ACA    13

300     ZZZ    33
```

original dataframe:

```
           V_vatego
    0        AA 
    1       AAC   
    2       ABB     
    3       AAC     
    4       DA  
    5       AAC
................
```

where I would like to replace(or add another) variable by the 'Time' values for each instance :

```
    v_catego  new_v_catego
0        AA   353
1       AAC   136
2       ABB     2
3       AA    353
4       AAC   136
.................
```

I know in R there is a simple function that does this. Is there an equivalent in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), but before you have to set same categories in both `Series` (columns) by [`add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html):

```
print df
  v_catego  Time
0       AA   353
1      AAC   136
2      ABB     2
3       AA   353
4      AAC   136

print df1
  v_catego  Time
0      ABC     1
1      ACA    13

#remember old cat in df1
old_cat = df1['v_catego']

#set same categories in both dataframes in column v_catego
df1['v_catego'] = df['v_catego'].cat.add_categories(df1['v_catego'])
df['v_catego'] = df['v_catego'].cat.add_categories(old_cat)
print df.v_catego
0     AA
1    AAC
2    ABB
3     AA
4    AAC
Name: v_catego, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [AA, AAC, ABB, ABC, ACA]

print df1.v_catego
0     AA
1    AAC
Name: v_catego, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [AA, AAC, ABB, ABC, ACA]
```

```
print pd.concat([df,df1])
  v_catego  Time
0       AA   353
1      AAC   136
2      ABB     2
3       AA   353
4      AAC   136
0       AA     1
1      AAC    13
```

EDIT:

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print df
   v_catego
0        AA
1       AAC
2       ABB
3        AA
4       AAC
5       ABB
6        AA
7       AAC
8        AA
9       AAC
10      AAC
11      ABB
12       AA
13      AAC
14      ABB
15       AA
16      AAC
17       AA
18      AAC
```

```
df1 = df['v_catego'].value_counts()
                    .reset_index(name='count')
                    .rename(columns={'index': 'v_catego'})
print df1
  v_catego  count
0      AAC      8
1       AA      7
2      ABB      4

print pd.merge(df,df1,on=['v_catego'], how='left' )
   v_catego  count
0        AA      7
1       AAC      8
2       ABB      4
3        AA      7
4       AAC      8
5       ABB      4
6        AA      7
7       AAC      8
8        AA      7
9       AAC      8
10      AAC      8
11      ABB      4
12       AA      7
13      AAC      8
14      ABB      4
15       AA      7
16      AAC      8
17       AA      7
18      AAC      8
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply Jezrael. I added further comments. I think it's clearer now...

Comment: That hit the spot!